# fcgi application does not see environment variables from SSL certificate

Tags: c++, apache, ssl-certificate, fastcgi, getenv

I have a problem trying to get client SSL certificate parameter from FCGI process environment:

```
auto client_ou = std::getenv(SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU);//ou is NULL
```

fcgi application is running under apache and in apache config I have:

```
<Directory "/var/www/webchannel/fcgi-bin">
            SetHandler fcgid-script
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertDat
            SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
            ...
</Directory>
```

I assume that Apache should pass SSL client certificate parameters to application but I failed to get it.

I also tried to use `QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment()` but result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it.

Apache configuration is right, he passes params in http request header not in environment.